# How to Align a trailing string to the bottom right corner of a TextView

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

In the picture bellow i want the `Footnote` string to always appear floating to the right edge of the Textview:

[image]

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
SpannableString item = new SpannableString ("Main text");
builder.append (item);
builder.append ("  ");
String footnote = "Footnote";
int len = footnote.length();
SpannableString subitem = new SpannableString (footnote);
subitem.setSpan (new ForegroundColorSpan (color), 0, len, 0);
subitem.setSpan (new AbsoluteSizeSpan (12, true), 0, len, 0);
subitem.setSpan (new AlignmentSpan.Standard (Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE), 0, len, 0);
builder.append (subitem);

myTextView.setText (builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this ? I need the same alignment

Comment: @SpeedDemon No I couldn't find a solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by using 2 textviews in frame layout and set the value of layout_gravity as right and bottom of 2nd second textview.

> android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"

Example:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flString"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHighlighted"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:text="Footnote"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#0000ff" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In case of single line, second highlighted word overlaps the text. It can be handled programatically:

```
/**
 * Used to create 2 text view text in single line like :
 *
 * Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text    |Footnote|
 *
 * @param frameLayout         FrameLayout
 * @param tvTitle             TextView   
 * @param tvHighlighted       TextView
 *       Directly "View" can be used as param type, but for this case only I                     
 *         have used dedicated Views and ViewGroup.
 */
public static void manageTextViews(final FrameLayout frameLayout, final TextView tvTitle, final TextView tvHighlighted) {
    tvTitle.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int lineCount = tvTitle.getLineCount();
                Rect bounds = new Rect();
                tvTitle.getLineBounds(lineCount > 0 ? lineCount - 1 : 0, bounds);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams fllp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                fllp.gravity = (Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT);
                if (frameLayout.getWidth() <= (bounds.width() + tvBuyable.getWidth() + 10)) {
                    fllp.setMargins(0, tvTitle.getLineHeight() + 5, 0, 0);
                } else {
                    fllp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                }
                tvHighlighted.setLayoutParams(fllp);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e(ClassName + ".manageTextViews()", "mTxtTitle.post", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```